# Tesseract Pulling from Multiple Chests to Multiple Locations

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Okay, so I am having some issues with Tessearcts form Thermal Expansion 3 in Minecraft.

The tesseracts are set correctly with their settings, sending side set to sending on frequency 1 and receiving end set to receive on frequency 1. I know they both work because if I hook up a single chest with items required by the receiving line of machines, it works fine. So I know the receiving side works just fine.

The sending side of the Tesseract, with one chest, works fine. But as soon as I connect a second chest with different items in it not currently required by the receiving side, it no longer works properly and the entire system gums up and then shuts down sending any items at all.

So Chest->TE ItemDucts->Tesseract Works
And Chestx2->TE ItemDucts->Tesseract Works when items in both chests have a destination on the receiving side.
But Chestx2->TE ItemDucts-Tesseract does not work when one item is not required or is full by the receiving sides machines.

Sending Side: 3 chests, bonemeal, bloodwood saplings, lettuce seeds.
Example ... Farm 1 requires: Bonemeal and Saplings, Farm 2 requires Bonemeal and Lettuce Seeds. When the first farm is full on saplings and both farms are full on bonemeal, but still needs lettuce seeds, the entire system gums up from sending anything else and the ends of the ItemDucts become stuffed and nothing will move from any chest even if it is or becomes required on the other side.

Ideally, I am looking for a way to have all my farms supplies hooked up to one tesseract sending point, where each farm will receive the items it needs via its tesseract. But because not all the farms do not receive the same items, it does not work as the sending side gums up as the pipes become stuffed.

Note: I have tried setting the sending side to Send&Receive and put pipes from the tesseract back into the chest to try and manager the overflow issue, but it does not work either.

Can you help me with this issue? Why wont my tesseract pull from a needed chest when another chest of items not needed is present on the line?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are using the same frequency for all your tesseracts... Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The way that item ducts work means that they need a destination for the items to be sent properly, there will be an item in the tesseract and then on the other side it won't pull it out because it has no where to go.

On the side you want to receive items to create an overflow chest until you have proper destinations for your items.

If you were to use buildcraft pipes this wouldn't happen because they "aren't smart" and will just pump items out at any point.

Hope this helps